# How to calculate the Minkowski bound .

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $ K=\mathbb{Q(\alpha)}$ and $x^3-x-1$ the minimal polynomial having $\alpha$ as  root . The degree over $\mathbb{Q}$ is 3 and the Minkowski bound says $$N(a) \leq \frac{n!}{n^n}(\frac{4}{\pi})^s\sqrt{|d_k|}$$
Now I know that  $$3=n=r+2s   $$ .
The polynomial has 2 complex roots and one real root .

Thus it holds $$r=1 ,s=1 $$ .
My problem is calculating the discriminant .

Comment: Tell us your definition of the discriminant. Have you ever computed the discriminant of a number field with degree greater than 2?

Answer (score 1):

The discriminant of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is a square times the discriminant of the number field $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$. By means of the resultant we find that
$$\Delta(f)=R(f,f')=R(x^3-x-1,3x^2-1)=-23,$$
which is squarefree, and hence $d_k=-23$.